# Yii2- Failed to create Mongodb models using Gii

Tags: mongodb, yii2, gii

I can't `create MongoDb models` using Gii module code generator.
 Gets the below **error :**

```
Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: common\components\MongoConnection::getTableSchema()
```

Answer (score 1):

Gii should not be used to create MongoDB Models.

MongoDB documents may change from one to another and there is no "collection definiton", as oposed to "table schemas" where you can get all column names and types.

This is the reason why a model cannot be created automatically and should be created manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gii component to help you generate MongoDB ActiveRecords.
Here's a little YouTube video that shows you exactly how it modify Yii2 configuration, create an active record and generate a CRUD controller.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1urmws7hz5Q